# How to create a table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

when I run this code it won't be able to create table

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,

   ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
   
);
```

Comment: I think you missed the schema name before table name. https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-create-table/

Comment: Remove the `,` after the address column.

Comment: Unrelated, but do not use the  `char` data type. It has absolutely no advantages whatsoever, but several annoying disadvantages.

Comment: And use VARCHAR2, it's Oracle.

Comment: @dnoeth: `varchar` will automatically be replaced with `varchar2` in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

To create a new table in Oracle Database, you should remeber some rules

i don't know what kind of error you face

so i have some suggestion

1. ADDRESS type between square brackets > [ADDRESS]
2. Not use Coma at end

```html
  CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   [ADDRESS]  CHAR (25)
);
```

Comment: `[ADDRESS]`  is an invalid identifier in standard SQL and Oracle

Comment: yea, but we define under Square[] brackets that's by this behave  like a normal identifier.

Comment: That's not a "normal identifier" and it simply won't work in Oracle